# What are the best ways to get SUS score on mockups?

Tags: usability, usability-testing, mockup, sus

Can we just showcase static mockups to users and as them to respond to SUS questionnaire?
Or, is it good to provide a clickable mockups so that they can get a feel of the workflow?

Do we have any accepted standard practice around this?

Answer (score 3):

> **System Usability Scale questions**
>
> 1. I think that I would like to use this system frequently.
> 2. I found the system unnecessarily complex.
> 3. I thought the system was easy to use.
> 4. I think that I would need the support of a technical person to be
>      able to use this system.
> 5. I found the various functions in this system were well integrated.
> 6. I thought there was too much inconsistency in this system.
> 7. I would imagine that most people would learn to use this system very
>      quickly.
> 8. I found the system very cumbersome to use.
> 9. I felt very confident using the system.
> 10. I needed to learn a lot of things before I could get going with this system.

The System Usability Scale (SUS) measures the user's perception of usability. Some of the questions are really hard to answer without actually using the system.

Questions 8, 9 and 10 explicitly ask about the user's actual experience with the system. Questions 1-4 could work for mockups as well (but get a slightly different meaning then - asking about the user's expectations instead of experience). Questions 5-7 are about how the various parts fit together, and might difficult to answer with just static prototypes.

So the SUS is best fitted for situations where users can actually interact with the system, and get a feel of the workflow. However, you may not necessarily need actual working prototypes for this - paper prototypes with a facilitator can work as well.